# MySQL: Select ALL with GROUP BY doesn't work

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm trying to select all columns from a database table and group it by one special column:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `email`
```

But I get an error:

```
#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'gassupplytool.ggg_nitrogen.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

I have done it for years this way without getting any problems. In this case I am working on a foreign server. Can anyone help?

Comment: The duplicate link explains what you can do to make your MySQL behave the way did previously.  The jist here is that MySQL has a server mode called `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` which, if enabled, will not allow a query like the one you wrote, which selects columns not appearing in the `GROUP BY` clause (or in an aggregate function).

Comment: I was going to answer, but this question literally gets asked here once per day, and I'm certain it is already well covered here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: OK, thanks Tim. Sorry for duplicate, but I didn't knew what to search for :-)

Comment: "I have done it for years this way without getting any problems" Oh dear. We can only hope you haven't worked on anything important :-(

Comment: @strawberry: many major customer projects. What is wrong with this? Using mysql.com as reference...

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a74d4/2 - I guarantee that you have done this, or something like it.

Comment: Using group by with the imprecise mysql only syntax provides "approximations", or worse, in the columns not specified by the group by clause. It is imprecise and a long way from good practice.  You should use ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY  and queries that comply with it.